# How to call functions of different php files

Tags: php, api, rest

I am trying to implement a PHP REST API.

**api.php**

```
<?php
    $path = 'api/';

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request = substr(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $path), strlen($path));

    echo $request;  
?>
```

After redirecting all my requests to api.php, I want to be able to call the desired function, that might reside in a different file.

Now, for example, an AJAX request might look like `'api/user/5'`, method `DELETE`.

I want my API to be able to call the `user.php` file, with `DELETE` and `$id=5` as parameters.
How can I do that? How to execute code that resides in a different file?

Comment: Are you using any kind of MVC framework or anything?

Comment: No framework. But I'd like to follow the MVC approach for both frontend and backend. Frontend is ExtJS MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three ways of doing this:

- Include the file  `require('user.php')`  - remember to check the method inside!
- use cURL to execute it (you may want to add some features to prevent others from doing this
- execute it from command line with parameters like:

  ```
   exec("php -q user.php $method $id")
  ```

To get the HTTP method just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Answer (score 1):

Simple use include.

For example:
(assumptions: api/user/5 is translated via your server to be api.php?function=user&value=5)

api.php:

```
<?php
valid_functions = array("users", "others");
//so you don't have errors of file not found if someone mistypes the url;
if (in_array($_GET["function"], valid_functions)){ 
    include "{$_GET["function"]}.php";
}
```

user.php:

```
<?php
echo "User id is {$_GET["value"]}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the file before you call the function.

```
include 'yourFileName.php';
validateHostName('yourHostName');
```

you can also use

```
require_once('yourFileName.php');
```

May be Help you